# Create multiple folders and sub-folders

Tags: windows-7, script, files-folders

I have been using this script to make folders using a text file. How do I add subfolders?

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %d in (Panels.txt) do md %d
```

Currently, the script makes folders Panel-A; Panel-B etc to Panel-Z.

I need sub-folders undel each Panel-* folder called:

- 2014_Products
- 2013_Products

The new folder structure would be:

- Panel-A\2014_Products
- Panel-A\2013_Products
- Panel-B\2014_Products
- Panel-B\2013_Products
- .
- .
- Panel-Z\2014_Products
- Panel-Z\2013_Products

How do I add the sub-folders?

Comment: Can you show your Panels.txt please? Add the content of it by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell for this. I haven't tested the below method yet, but it should work.

1. Create a CSV file in the root of the folder you want to start with.

   - Best to use Excel, or another spreadsheet editor, and "Save As" comma-delimited CSV.
   - Name the file `FolderNames.csv`
   - Make two columns, with the headers `Name` and `Type`
   - Put the name of each Panel folder in the Name column, with `Folder` in the Type column.
   - Put the name of each Products folder (only once each, not for every Panel/Products combination) in the Name column, with `Subfolder` in the Type column.
2. Open a new PowerShell console.
3. Navigate to the folder containing `FolderNames.csv`
4. Run the following command:

---

```
$Folders=Import-Csv FolderNames.csv;$Folders|?{$_.Type-eq'Folder'}|%{$ParentName=$_.Name;New-Item "$ParentName" -ItemType Directory;$Folders|?{$_.Type-eq'Subfolder'}|%{$ChildName=$_.Name;New-Item "$ParentName\$ChildName" -ItemType Directory}}
```

The command above is really a script condensed into a (somewhat lengthy) one-liner. Here's an expanded, and commented, version:

```
# Import FoldersNames.csv into a variable called $Folders
# This will create an array of objects which have the Name and Type properties as defined in the CSV.

$Folders=Import-Csv FolderNames.csv;

# Filter $Folders down to just objects with a Type value of 'Folder'.
# ? is a built-in alias for Where-Object.

$Folders|?{$_.Type-eq'Folder'}|

# Send the filtered objects into a ForEach-Object loop.
# % is a built-in alias for ForEach-Object.
%{
    # Store the current object's Name in $ParentName.

    $ParentName=$_.Name;

    # Create a new directory named $ParentName.

    New-Item "$ParentName" -ItemType Directory;

    # Filter $Folders down to just objects with a Type value of 'Subfolder'.

    $Folders|?{$_.Type-eq'Subfolder'}|

    # Send the filtered objects into a ForEach-Object loop.
    %{
        # Store the current object's Name in $ChildName.

        $ChildName=$_.Name;

        # Create a new subfolder in $ParentName called $ChildName.

        New-Item "$ParentName\$ChildName" -ItemType Directory
    }
}
```

Note that this solution isn't very scalable as-is. If you need to make deeper layers of subfolders, or put different subfolders in certain folders depending on their name, it won't really be simple to adapt this script to your needs. However, it should serve the purpose as outlined in your question.